# pm2-runtime ecosystem npm script fail

Tags: docker, pm2

****Google Translator used****

I don't know why "ecosystem.config.js" is still included in npm agrs ...
So in the "ecosystem.config.js" file, args only has run and start, but when you build a docker, it looks like it works with npm ecosystem.config.js run start.
Please tell me why

// dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN npm install pm2 -g

COPY . /usr/src/nuxt/

WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt/

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080

RUN npm run build
# start the app
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "ecosystem.config.js"]
```

// ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
apps: [
    {
        name: 'webapp',
        exec_mode: 'cluster',
        instances: 2,
        script: 'npm',
        args: ['run', 'start'],
        env: {
            HOST: '0.0.0.0',
            PORT: 8080
        },
        autorestart: true,
        max_memory_restart: '1G'
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with ecosystem.config.js, I ended up using the yaml format instead: create process.yaml and enter your config>

```
apps:
- script: /app/index.js
name: 'app'
instances: 2
error_file: ./errors.log
exec_mode: cluster
env:
  NODE_ENV: production
  PORT: 12345
```

Then in the docker file:

```
COPY ./dist/index.js /app/
COPY process.yaml /app/

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
# Expose the listening port of your app
EXPOSE 12345
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "/app/process.yaml"]
```

Just change the directories and files to the way you want things setup

Comment: I used the yaml approach and it worked. Thank you @it-officer